# Why does my Xcode project always complain about the compiled version of MonorailSwift?

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage

I am trying to compile an Xcode project which makes use of the [MonorailSwift](https://github.com/river2202/MonorailSwift?tab=readme-ov-file) library, but I keep running into the following error:

> Compiled module was created by a different version of the compiler '5.8.0.124.2'; rebuild 'MonorailSwift' and try again: /Users/...some redacted directories here.../MonorailSwift.framework/Modules/MonorailSwift.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule

My Xcode version is 15.3, and when I install my dependencies via Carthage, it says `*** Checking out MonorailSwift at "1.5.5"`.

Please forgive me if I am leaving out any essential details. This is my first time working on an iOS project, so I appreciate any help I can get.

I have deleted the `/MonorailSwift.framework` directory and re-imported it with Carthage multiple times. It is installing v1.5.5 each time, and I still get the error.